# How to change the variables name with "for loop"?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, var

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and need some quick help.
When "for loop" begins, I want `data1` to change to `data2`, `data3` and so on. I've tried many expressions like `("data[i]")` and so on, but nothing happens. Can you help me?

```
for (var i=1;i<10;i++){
                document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = "text";
            }
```

Comment: Use document.getElementById("data" + i).innerHTML = "text";?

Comment: That's a very common antipattern. Use a common class, instead of multiple id's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use string concatenation.

```
for (var i=1;i<10;i++){
     document.getElementById("data" + i).innerHTML = "text";
}
```